# Java dice roll with unexpected random number

Tags: java, if-statement

I've written a simple Java program to display the results of 20 dice rolls on the console. The results I'm getting are listed below:

```
3
1
java.util.Random@62efae3b
1
5
4
1
java.util.Random@62efae3b
1
java.util.Random@62efae3b
java.util.Random@62efae3b
1
6
java.util.Random@62efae3b
1  
java.util.Random@62efae3b
java.util.Random@62efae3b
1
2
3
3
```

When I ran it for a few times, the string after "@" is different, but basically in the same format. What have I done wrong?

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class QiProb3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random diceNumber = new Random();

        for (int count = 0; count <= 20; count++) {
            if ((diceNumber.nextInt(6) + 1) == 1) {
                System.out.println("1");
            } else if ((diceNumber.nextInt(6) + 1) == 2) {
                System.out.println("2");
            } else if ((diceNumber.nextInt(6) + 1) == 3) {
                System.out.println("3");
            } else if ((diceNumber.nextInt(6) + 1) == 4) {
                System.out.println("4");
            } else if ((diceNumber.nextInt(6) + 1) == 5) {
                System.out.println("5");
            } else if ((diceNumber.nextInt(6) + 1) == 6) {
                System.out.println("6");
            } else {
                System.out.println(diceNumber);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
else {
    System.out.println(diceNumber);
}
```

You are printing the address of `diceNumber` by invoking its default `toString()` function in your else clause.
That is why you are getting the `java.util.Random@62efae3b`

The **more critical issue** is **why** it gets to the 'else' clause, I believe that is not your intention.
**Note:** In the question, a new number is generated in each `if/else if` clause, which is why the code actually gets to the final `else` clause.

What you should be doing is:

```
for (int count = 0; count < 20; count++) {

    int rollValue = diceNumber.nextInt(6) + 1;

    if (rollValue == 1) {
        System.out.println("1");
    } else if (rollValue == 2) {
        System.out.println("2");
    } else if (rollValue == 3) {
        System.out.println("3");
    } else if (rollValue == 4) {
        System.out.println("4");
    } else if (rollValue == 5) {
        System.out.println("5");
    } else if (rollValue == 6) {
        System.out.println("6");
    } else {
        // This else is now redundant
        System.out.println(diceNumber);
    }
}
```

or a more straight-forward method would be:

```
// count < 20 instead of count <= 20
for (int count = 0; count < 20; count++) {

    int rollValue = diceNumber.nextInt(6) + 1;
    System.out.println(rollValue);
}
```

> Credit goes to 'Elliott Frisch' for realizing that the loop is
>   executed 21 times instead of 20.

Comment: +1 for the elegant approach & addressing the more important "why" question. For clarity, it might be good to spell out what's happening in plain English (i.e. "if the 1st roll is not 1, roll again; if that next roll is not 2, roll again, etc...)

Comment: @tavnab I don't think he needs the 1st roll to be 1, etc? He just needs to display the results of 20 dice rolls, based on his question. There is no notion of 'rolling again'.

Comment: @f_qi Glad to know that you understand what's the problem now! :)

Comment: @Gosu what I mean is that the OP's original code kept re-rolling the dice (i.e. calling `diceNumber.nextInt()`) when each `if/else if` failed to be entered. On first glance, or if you're new to programming, it might not be clear that that's what's happening & the fact that the final `else` is entered at all can be confusing.

Answer (score 4):

#### You're Re-Rolling

With each `if` you re-roll the dice. Store the value, and test it!

```
Random diceNumber = new Random();
for (int count = 0; count <= 20; count++) {
    int roll = diceNumber.nextInt(6) + 1; 
    if (roll == 1) {
        System.out.println("1");
    } else if (roll == 2) {
        System.out.println("2");
    } else if (roll == 3) {
        System.out.println("3");
    } else if (roll == 4) {
        System.out.println("4");
    } else if (roll == 5) {
        System.out.println("5");
    } else if (roll == 6) {
        System.out.println("6");
    } else {
        System.out.println("RNG Error: " + diceNumber);
    }
}
```

#### It Could be More Concise

Your posted code might be shortened like

```
for (int count = 0; count <= 20; count++) {
    int roll = diceNumber.nextInt(6) + 1;
    System.out.println(roll); 
}
```

#### Note

Also, you get 21 rolls using the above `<= 20` test.

Comment: I had no idea he was doing 21 rolls instead of 20, nice spot!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without the large if-else ladder:

```
    int x = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 20){
        x = (int)(Math.random() * 7);
        if(x != 0)
        {
        System.out.println((int)Math.floor(x));
        i++;
        }
    }
```

Math.random() gets a value between 0 and 1 and this value is multiplied to 7. If the dice turns out to be zero, skip the roll and do another one. The Math.floor() value will round the decimal value down to the nearest integer (if product = 6.2 then the output of the roll will be 6).